# Changing the integration limit

Tags: calculus

I was reading the derivation of $E = mc^{2}$ but I am stuck in a very simple minor detail. In the derivation, we have the kinetic energy (K.E.) as $\int_{0}^{s} F \, ds$, where $F$ is constant.

Then we have

\begin{align*}
    \int_{0}^{s} F \, ds &= \int_{0}^{s} \frac{d(\gamma m v)}{dt} \, ds \\
                         &= \int_{0}^{mv} vd(\gamma m v) \\
                         &= \int_{0}^{v} vd(\frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}})
\end{align*}

I cannot see how the integration bounds change. Do we make some kind of $u$ substitution?

Comment: You sure the definition of the kinetic energy is correct? Having the same variable both as limit of integration and as varible of integration is not really well defined.

Comment: @Davide I've checked the textbook again. The definition of the kinetic energy is correct. Since it is a physics textbook it may not be rigorous as a mathematics textbook but I've seen lots of examples like this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this single variable case it is a forgivable sin to denote the integration variable and the integration limit by the same symbol.

- You should know from variable substitution that this goes *always* hand in
  hand with a change in the integration limits.

Remembering that $\gamma=\frac1{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$ will however show a few errors:
\begin{align*}
    \int_{0}^{s} F \, ds &= \int_{0}^{s} \frac{d(\gamma m v)}{dt} \, ds \\
                         &= \int_{0}^{\color{red}\gamma\, mv} v\,d(\gamma m v) \\
                         &= \int_{0}^{v} v\,\underbrace{\frac{d\Bigg(\frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\Bigg)}{\color{red}{dv}}}\,\color{red}{dv}\,.
\end{align*}
Taking the underbraced derivative leads to a slightly cumbersome integral over $v$ but ultimately to the correct solution that the kinetic energy is
$$
E_{kin}=\gamma mc^2-mc^2\,
$$
where $m$ is the constant rest mass.

Integration by-parts makes it less cumbersome:

> \begin{align}&-\int_0^v \frac{mv}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\,dv+\frac{mv^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}=mc^2\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}-mc^2+\frac{mv^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\\&=\gamma mc^2-mc^2\,.\end{align}

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I cannot make up my mind on how we change the integration limit from row 1 to row 2.  I know in the linear case treating the derivative as a fraction is okay but I nevertheless tried to make a u substitution to understand what's going on properly, but I could not arrive at a result. Am I being overcautious?

Comment: One can never be too cautious. In row one we calculate the work done when we move against the force $F$ from $s=0$ to $s\,.$ In row two this becomes $\int_0^pv\,dp$ where $p=\gamma mv$ is relativistic momentum. When you go back to Calculus I you will find that we had to transform both integration limits. The lower limit of zero reflects the silent assumption I made that the body that is accelerated was initially at rest.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, the derivation is maybe not perfectly rigorous, but we *can* see that a substitution is being made not only because the bounds of integration changed but because the *variable* of integration changed.

Notice that in the first line the integral is being taken with respect to $ds$, but in the second it is being taken with respect to $d(\gamma mv)$, i.e. the new variable of integration is $\rho = \gamma mv$, the (relativistic) momentum. If you go through the substitution more thoroughly (and preferably use different symbols for $v$ as a variable in the integral and as a bound of the integral) you should get something that resembles the given result.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{{\displaystyle #1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sr}[2]{\,\,\,\stackrel{{#1}}{{#2}}\,\,\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
& m = mass.\quad m_{0} = rest\ mass
\\[5mm]
\color{#44f}{W\pars{\vec{a}\to\vec{b}}} & \equiv \color{#44f}{\int_{\vec{\,a}}^{\vec{\,b}}\vec{\on{F}}\cdot\dd\vec{\on{r}}} =
\int_{\vec{a\,}}^{\vec{b\,}}
\totald{\pars{m\vec{\on{v}}}}{t}\cdot\dd\vec{\on{r}} \\[5mm] & =
\int_{\vec{a\,}}^{\vec{b\,}}
\dd\pars{m\vec{\on{v}}}\cdot\totald{\vec{\on{r}}}{t}
=
\int_{\vec{a\,}}^{\vec{b\,}}\pars{\vec{\on{v}}\,\dd m + m\,\dd\vec{\on{v}}}\cdot\vec{\on{v}}
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{\vec{a\,}}^{\vec{b\,}}\bracks{\on{v}^{2}\,\dd m + {1 \over 2}m\,\dd\pars{\on{v}^{2}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{\vec{a\,}}^{\vec{b\,}}\bracks{\on{v}^{2}\,\dd m + {1 \over 2}m\bracks{\pars{{2c^{2} \over m} - {2\on{v}^{2} \over m}}\dd m}}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{\color{#44f}{\int_{\vec{a\,}}^{\vec{b\,}}c^{2}\,\dd m}}
\\[5mm] &\mbox{Note that}\ m =
{m_{0} \over \root{\rule{0pt}{5mm}1 - \on{v}^{2}/c^{2}}}
\\[5mm] & \implies m^{2}\pars{1 - {\on{v}^{2} \over c^{2}}} = m_{0} = \mbox{constant}
\\[5mm] & \implies \dd\bracks{m^{2}\pars{1 - {\on{v}^{2} \over c^{2}}}} = 0 
\end{align}

Comment: This vector notation starts getting weird. And it cannot be that the integration limits never change. That was OP's main question.

Comment: @KurtG I didn’t do it because it seem to obvious to me. Any way, it must be $m_{\vec{r}_a}$ and a similar one at $\vec{b}$. I just want to show the main idea. The reader can polish it. Thanks.

Comment: @KurtG TOO obvious…